# Шифрование и дешифровка Javascript

Tags: base64, javascript, mcrypt, md5

Есть закодированные строки:

```
 .P0|zt`n7+jfencqmtN{3~swuk"4S!QUWS+laacy0*041C<39

 ``}dxbeg2uciewkwE$ztokvxa-ty{py*v``y!xcsm=74t{9
```

Метод кодировки:

```
function ae(ai) {
        var f = "";
        for (var c = 0; c < ai.length; c++) {
            f += String.fromCharCode(ai.charCodeAt(c) ^ (1 + (ai.length - c) % 32))
        }
        return f
    }
```

Вопрос: Как расшифровать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это обычное [XOR-шифрование](http://kriptografea.narod.ru/XOR.html). Расшифровывается той же функцией, что и шифруется.

```
enc = '.P0|zt`n7+jfencqmtN{3~swuk"4S!QUWS+laacy0*041C<39';
dec = ae(enc);
```

P. S. md5 - не шифрование, это хеширование. base64 шифрованием можно назвать с натяжкой.

Answer (score 2):

Примените эту же функцию к зашифрованной строке.
Расшифрованная первая строка:

```
<A style="background-color:#E4EFEB;color:#837F80;
```

Вторая строка:

```
position:relative;display:block;font-size:11px;
```